# Grid view within Modal PopUp Extender?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I'm developing a mapping application in ASP.net C#.

I have a textbox and button which searches a DB on postcode and returns the results into a Grid view on my aspx page...

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
// SDE connection string to extract postcode from ADDRESS (sde) table. 

private SqlConnection m_sqlConn;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void ShowMsg(string strMessage)
{
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        if (txtPostCode.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            m_sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
            m_sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=sde;User
            ID=Tom;Password = Password1";

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = m_sqlConn;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ADDRESS"
                                        + " WHERE Postcode = '" + txtPostCode.Text + "'";

            m_sqlConn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        else
        {
            ShowMsg("Error - No Postal Addresses Returned");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowMsg("Error - " + ex.Message);
    }

}

            private bool CloseDB()
{
    try
    {
        m_sqlConn.Close();
        return (true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return (false);
    }

}
```

}

This works fine. I now want to set the Data Grid within a Modal PopUp whereby the user clicks the search button and the results table is returned modally. I've tried to set it up with a fake ControlID button like so but no luck...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

```
 <asp:Button id="BtnFake"  runat="server" Style="display: none"/>

<table id="ModalGrid">

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">

 </asp:GridView>

 <asp:Button id="Button2"  runat="server" Text="OK" />

 </table>

<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="BtnFake" PopupControlID="ModalGrid" DropShadow="false"       
    BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground"
    CancelControlID="BtnOK" BehaviorID="ModalGrid"       RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowScroll">
     </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Any ideas? sure I'm doing something obvious wrong. Cheers.

Comment: What means _"but no luck.."_? Are you usign UpdatePanels? Why have you set `CancelControlID` to "BtnOK" instead also to "BtnFake"? Btw, use `using` statament instead.

Comment: ModalPopupExtender TargetControlID references the control that would trigger the modal, wouldn't that be the search button (BtnOk)? Because your code is pointing to BtnFake as the TargetControl for the popup;

Comment: Thanks guys. I've now got BtnOK (search button) as the Target Control ID. and  The modal popup window shows on search button click but the Grid View is not displayed?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders: I assume that OP wants to open the modal-popup from codebehind. Then you need to use an invisible "Fake"-button. You would call `ModalPopupExtender1.Show()` to show it manually.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: I see, it seems like i misunderstood what he said. I thought he wanted to open the modal when the user clicked the search button.

Comment: Yes, can I use code behind in the .cs to display the grid view within my modal popup? The results display fine within the default page, just not when incorporated into a Modal Popup...

Comment: So the user enters the postcode they want to search for in the textbox and hits the search button. The SQL connection then does its thing and returns all address rows with that postcode into a grid view. I want these results to automatically display in a modal popup without the use of another Target button to launch the popup. So I need the Search button to handle the SQL then display the Grid View results in the modal popup if possible?

Comment: I think you have to wrap the grid with a panel with the following id: ModalGrid. Thats what you filled on the ModalPopupExtender PopupControlID property.

Comment: Hi, yes, it's within a table (<table id="ModalGrid">), sorry missed that bit of HTML out. I've had no issues with Modal Popup display before, It's just embedding this GridView I'm struggling with as normally you just set a button as a target control but in this case my Search button already handles the SQL query etc and therefore doesn't seem to be able to handle being the target of the modal too.

Comment: Can you complete the code on your post? Since that table is not on it.

Comment: I've edited the code. Was literally just missing <table id="ModalGrid"> Do I need to include some sort of databind within the C#?

Comment: It is still weird, there is no button with the id "BtnOK" on the code you posted. There is one "Button2" tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In a scenario where you set a modal popups `TargetControlId` to a dummy field you have to explicitly call `ModalPopupExtender1.Show();` to display the modal.
2. Where is BtnOK? Shouldn't it be Button2?

Tip - using a button for a dummy field is a bit of an overkill, use something simple like a `<span>` instead

Below is a working example if you get stuck, but I believe calling `ModalPopupExtender1.Show();` should sort you out:

**ASPX:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<span ID="dummy" runat="server" />
Post code:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostcode" runat="server" /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Search" />
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="modalPanel" CssClass="modalPanel">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="dummy"
    PopupControlID="modalPanel" BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground"
     CancelControlID="btnCancel" BehaviorID="ModalGrid">
 </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
</form>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<PostalCode> codes = new List<PostalCode>()
    {
        new PostalCode{ Code="000",Province="District 0" },
        new PostalCode{ Code="111",Province="District 1" }
    };

    string code = txtPostcode.Text;

    if (codes.Where(c => c.Code == code).Any())
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = codes.Where(c => c.Code == code);
        GridView1.DataBind();
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
}
```

**Class I've used for testing:**

```
public class PostalCode
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
}
```